# Hide asterisk only for one field but show up for other fields

Tags: javascript

I have a text field and a dropdown field shown below

When I select any value from the dropdown field called 'REASONS', hide the asterisk of  VEHICLE_NO field , I'm doing the below but doesnt work,
asteriskV ID is used for other fields to show/hide asterisks, my goal is to hide only for VEHICLE_NO and not for other fields when any of the value is selected from REASONS dropdown, how can i achieve this?

```
   <table>
   <tr><td><font id="asteriskV" color="red">*</font>VEHICLE TAG:</td>
   <td>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" id="VEHICLE_NO" class="MandatoryVTxt" NAME="VEHICLE_NO" size="25"></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><font color="red">*</font>1)Reasons:</td><td>
       <select id="REASONS"  name="REASONS" class="MandatoryDD" style="width:200px">
     </select>
   </td></tr>
  </table>

  $('#REASONS').change(function () {       
   var sel = $(this).val();   
    if (sel == '1117' || sel == '1116' || sel=='1120'  || sel=='1121'){
        $("#testingForm #VEHICLE_NO #asteriskV").hide();        
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear shwetha you can try this code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td><font id="asteriskV" color="red">*</font>VEHICLE TAG:</td>
          <td>
              <INPUT TYPE="text" id="VEHICLE_NO" class="MandatoryVTxt" NAME="VEHICLE_NO" size="25">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><font color="red">*</font>1)Reasons:</td>
          <td>
              <select id="REASONS" name="REASONS" class="MandatoryDD" style="width:200px">
                  <option>Select Reason</option>
                  <option value="1117">Reason 1</option>
                  <option value="1116">Reason 2</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>


  <script>
      $(function () {
          $('#REASONS').change(function () {
              var sel = $(this).val();
              if (sel == '1117' || sel == '1116' || sel == '1120' || sel == '1121') {
                  $("#asteriskV").hide();
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qaaf5vs9/

Comment: I have few more fields that use asteriskV , so I dont want to hide all the fields asterisk when the  dropdown value is selected from REASONS, I would like to hide only(i.e. asterisk)  VEHICLE TAG field,

Comment: <tr><td class="Dyno"><font id="asteriskD" color="red">*</font>TEST CITE/CELL:</td><td><INPUT TYPE="text" id="TEST_CITE_CELL" class="MandatoryDTxt" class="Dyno"  NAME="TEST_CITE_CELL" size="25"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><font id="asteriskD" color="red">*</font>TEST START DATE:</td><td><INPUT TYPE="text" id="TEST_START_DATE" NAME="TEST_START_DATE" class="MandatoryDTxt" size="25" readonly></td></tr>   These fields asterisk should not be hidden.

Comment: simply use is for particular id $("#asteriskV").hide();

Comment: I am using select2 for dropdowns, check the below JS  , I cannot add  
  <option>Select Reason</option>
                  <option value="1117">Reason 1</option>
                  <option value="1116">Reason 2</option>
  
 generateDropDownList_kv("EInspection","getTeardownList","TeardownRequestForm","REASONS","0","-Select-",false);
 $('#TeardownRequestForm #REASONS').select2();

Comment: @shwetha: please share your complete html and js code in fiddle, so I can help you

Answer (score 0):

Add a class only to the font for VEHICLE_NO, and hide it using that class

```
    <table>
   <tr><td><font id="asteriskV" class="VEHICLE_NO" color="red">*</font>VEHICLE TAG:</td>
   <td>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" id="VEHICLE_NO" class="MandatoryVTxt" NAME="VEHICLE_NO" size="25"></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><font color="red">*</font>1)Reasons:</td><td>
       <select id="REASONS"  name="REASONS" class="MandatoryDD" style="width:200px">
     </select>
   </td></tr>
  </table>

  $('#REASONS').change(function () {       
   var sel = $(this).val();   
    if (sel == '1117' || sel == '1116' || sel=='1120'  || sel=='1121'){
        $(".VEHICLE_NO").hide();        
    }
    });
```

Comment: Tried, but not working                                                                            
 <tr><td><font id="asteriskV" class="Vehtag" color="red">*</font>VEHICLE TAG:</td><td><INPUT TYPE="text" id="VEHICLE_NO" class="MandatoryVTxt" NAME="VEHICLE_NO" size="25"></td></tr>                                                                                            
             if (sel == '1117' || sel == '1116' || sel=='1120'  || sel=='1121'){
  $(".Vehtag #asteriskV").hide();  
  
 } 
 else
 {
  $(".Vehtag #asteriskV").show(); 
 }
    });

Comment: I'll have to use class for font right? cos using the class of text field would hide the field and not the asterisk

Comment: Yes, the class should only be in the font if that's what you want to hide. Otherwise it will hide everything with that class

Comment: Try calling the hide() and show() like this

$(".Vehtag").hide();

$(".Vehtag").show();

Answer (score 0):

I'm as confused as jquery, where is the tag with 3 IDs? I think you want ...

```
$('#REASONS').change(function () {       
   var sel = $(this).val();   
    if (sel == '1117' || sel == '1116' || sel=='1120'  || sel=='1121'){
        $("#asteriskV").hide();        
    }
    });
```

and for select not change ...

```
$('#REASONS').focus(function() {       
   var sel = $(this).val();   
    if (sel == '1117' || sel == '1116' || sel=='1120'  || sel=='1121'){
        $("#asteriskV").hide();        
    }
    });
```

If you want to hide multible elements I suggest using a class for all elements and $(".allAsterisk").hide();